# "User cancelled the login process" error during facebook login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium, httpclient

I am using Facebook module 4.0.5, Titanium SDK 5.1.0 GA. My development platform is iOS.
Facebook login works fine when i set 
`forceDialogAuth= true.` But when i test with `forceDialogAuth= false` on device or in simulator it opens up the login window in Safari. After providing my credentials and logging in. It comes back to app but nothing happens i.e code inside `fb.loggedin` condition never executes. Main reason for this is that it takes too long to show response. And this is response i get

```
{"code":5,"error":"OTHER: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x7aeb9800 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x7aed8d60 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x7b91f620 "The request timed out."}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=200, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x7ae6c1d0, state: FBSessionStateClosed, loginHandler: 0x0, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x7b921680>, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0000-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}","success":false,"cancelled":false,"bubbles":true,"type":"login","source":{"id":"facebook"},"cancelBubble":false}
```

Is anybody familiar with this type of error. I don't understand why this error keeps coming. I am only trying to login user to authorize my app that's all. I have these permissions sets up.

```
fb.permissions = ['public_profile', 'email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

As of April 30th, 2015, Facebook no longer supports version 1.0 of their API, which includes the FQL and REST APIs. Only the Graph APIs will be supported. To be compatible with FB's API, this requires you should at least use a Ti Facebook module version 4.0+

There's no use in debugging a Ti FB module version <4.0

Comment: I tried with SDK 5.1.0 and latest Ti FB module. But problem is same. Only improvement is that now user comes back to app after input his credentials and also got response on Safari that you have already authorized this app.

Comment: I have edited my question with latest improvements. Could you take a look again.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of the module requires you to add some keys to your `tiapp.xml`:

https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/tree/master/ios#module-api

This is also in the documentation but I see the formatting is bad there so it's not that obvious. I will fix that.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook